# Master studies in Human Interaction Design for design background

Tags: career-development, ux-designer

My background is from User Interface design and now I want to pursue further to study about how user interact with interface and also devices. Thus I'm looking for suitable master program in European University, but most of them are in Computer Science faculty.

Such as:
- Human Media Interaction from University of Twente
- Design for Interaction from TU Delft

Anyone from design background already enrolled in these types of program? Could you give me some insights information whether I could apply for these programs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your goal is as you mention: "to study about how user interact with interface and also devices." Then I would recommend you to pursue studies on research methods, I would go for Social Sciences research methods made for psychologist, anthropologist, sociologist, etc. probably it would be out of your comfort zone since you would be subject of different teaching methods but since you already have a design background I would say having other point of view on how to see design research would be more enriching than pure design research.

I would also go to the Digital Humanities areas since they do research on diverse creative and experimental methodologies observe and interpret how human are interacting with technology.

For both I would recommend to look at the UK, places like UCL for Digital Humanities and Goldsmiths, LSE, etc. for Research Methods.

Maybe you could directly consider Design Research as a more straight and safe route, still if you have a bit of an oblique mindset as I do, you will value the richness that other disciplines can bring to your daily work.

Answer (score 1):

I followed TU delft Design for Interaction program and my bachelor was product design in METU. The program is for two years.

There are several courses about user centered design, usability and design projects. Last semester, the student works for his/her master thesis within a company.

You can apply these programs via their website and there are some conditions like English proficiency, some courses like that TU Delft gives to any student.

Some courses:

Contextualization, Exploring Interactions, Usability and Redesign, Interactive Technologies, User Experience related courses, and so on.Since I graduated in 2010, there may be some courses changed according to the industrial needs.